# Reset your Wordpress Password hosted on Azure with ClearDB

Tags: wordpress, azure, cleardb

1. Wordpress hosted on Azure with ClearDB.
2. Any pointers on how to reset the password ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: read this : https://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password

Answer (score 0):

From the Azure portal, find your ClearDB database. You can find this by selecting 'More services', and searching for MySql. You can use this URL to get there as well:

https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/Resources/resourceType/SuccessBricks.ClearDB%2Fdatabases

Select your database, and then you can choose the 'Manage database'option. This will bring you to the ClearDB Portal, where you can get your connection string.

You can connect to the ClearDB database using [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), and from there you can write SQL queries to reset your wordpress password (wp_users table):

http://www.wpexplorer.com/reset-wordpress-password-using-mysql/

I also recommend looking at the Azure MySQL offering. We've migrated our MySql databases to here and the experience has been great.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/cleardb-migration-to-azure-database-for-mysql/